# Merging files gives memory allocation error

Tags: r

I have two files like

```
> head(a)
  chr position
1   1   136962
2   1   562020
3   1   672948
> class(a)
[1] "data.frame"
>
```

And

```
> dim(b)
[1] 1855235      10
> head(b[,1:3])
            SNP chr position
1:  rs62635286          1    13116
2:  rs75454623          1    14930
3:    rs806731          1    30923
4: rs200943160          1    49298
5: rs116400033          1    51479
6: rs141149254          1    54490
> class(b)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
>
```

I want to find corresponding SNP in file b matched to position in file a so I did like this that gives memory allocation error.

```
> unique(merge(a,b,x.by=a$position,y.by=b$position)) 
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 137.2 Gb
```

I also tried rstudio cloud but uploading the bigger file never completes

Can you help me with task please?

The expected output would be something like

```
rs62635286  1   13116
rs376723915 1   91515
rs147061536 1   92858
rs62642131  1   135982
rs371474651 1   158006
rs201293782 1   665401
rs138476838 1   668374
rs1401137   1   2063094
rs3128293   1   2065339
```

> EDITED

```
> setDT(a)
> setkey(a, chr, position)
> setkey(b, chr, position)
Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) : 
  some columns are not in the data.table: chr,position
> setkey(b, Chromosome, Position)
> a[b, nomatch=0]
Error in bmerge(i, x, leftcols, rightcols, roll, rollends, nomatch, mult,  : 
  Incompatible join types: x.chr (factor) and i.Chromosome (integer). Factor columns must join to factor or character columns.
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this :

First you should work with the same class of object : `data.table` for fast merging operation

```
# Turning a to a data.table
setDT(a)
# b is already a data.table
```

Then you might have to set the keys of both table :

```
# I added chr in case you need to match the same position on a different chromosome.
setkey(a, chr, position)
setkey(b, chr, position)
```

Finally perform the joining operation :

```
a[b, nomatch=0]
```

Because you didn't provide the expected output, it might need some tuning !

Comment: Thank you I added the output of your command in my main post. I obtained error please can you have a look?

Comment: This error means the type of your chromosome columns don't match. You can check the type of all columns with `str(a)`. I suggest you keep the the integer format of the `b` table. This should update `a` column from factor to integer : `a[, chr := as.integer(chr)]`. It may work then !